# Backup a database using c#, the bak file gets bigger and bigger, how do I stop it from growing?

Tags: c#, database, backup

So the scenario is that It seems to append to the bak file when creating it, is it possible to stop it from doing that and just backup the current version?

here is my code

```
Server backFromServer = new Server(@"server ip add");
backFromServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
backFromServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "uname";
backFromServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "psd";
Database backFromDb = new Database();
backFromDb = backFromServer.Databases["dbname"];

Backup bkpDatabase = new Backup();
bkpDatabase.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
bkpDatabase.Database = backFromDb.Name;
bkpDatabase.Incremental = false;
bkpDatabase.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;                

BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(@"D:\backupfolder\backup.bak",
                                                  DeviceType.File);

bkpDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
bkpDatabase.SqlBackup(backFromServer);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set [Backup.Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.initialize.aspx) to true:

> "If True, the backup specified becomes
>   the first backup set on the media,
>   overwriting any existing backup sets
>   on the media. "